# how to get from mysql only one colum result with WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have to get the name's column with a WHERE mysql, but if do that i got the
whole row. I need only the name's result. can you help me?
thanks!

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = %s'
data=(res, )

mycursor.execute(sql, data)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
for x in myresult:
    print(x)
    if x==res:
        print("as")
        sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE pass =%s"
        data=(res2, )
        mycursor.execute(sql, data)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for i in myresult:
            if i==res2:
                pacsoka.starttt
```

Comment: i would expect that you should do this in the sql request....  or are you asking to edit the python code ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the query with this:

```
sql = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE pass =%s"
```

If you need additional columns, mention them along with name and separate column names with a comma (,)